# Java, strange timestamp format in microsecond?

Tags: java

How can I convert the following timestamp "2012-02-22T16:46:28.9870216+00:00" into a timestamp readable and processable by Java without losing any accuracy? what its data format?? for example about my goal, I receive 2 messages, read the timestamp in each message (as it written in my example above) compare between two timestamps to determine which is the old between them

by noting that the question below does not match what I need, it is different where they speak about timestamp format is different of 2012-02-22T16:46:28.9870216+00:00 which I did not know about it
[Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Comment: Looks like ISO 8601 with microseconds.

Comment: Granularity - 100ns I think.

Comment: I don't know really how to deal with it in Java, if you can help please ?

Comment: After the seconds you have microseconds and then time zone. And what do you mean by readable, also if you want to make the date 'shorter' you cannot do it without lossing precision (you could clarify if you don't mind for instance loose microsecond precision)

Comment: thank you @JoseDaSilva the answer number 1 below by gil.fernandes it was exactly what I need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse it with this [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME): `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "2012-02-22T16:46:28.9870216+00:00";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    System.out.println(dtf.parse(str));
}
```

If you run this code, you will see on the console:

```
{OffsetSeconds=0, InstantSeconds=1329929188},ISO resolved to 2012-02-22T16:46:28.987021600
```

**Update:**

Here is an updated response which shows how to convert the string to a `LocalDateTime` and allows date comparisons:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "2012-02-22T16:46:28.9870216+00:00";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    LocalDateTime lds = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf);
    System.out.println(lds);
    String str2 = "2012-02-22T16:46:28.9970430+00:00";
    String str3 = "2012-02-22T16:46:29.0270266+00:00";
    LocalDateTime lds2 = LocalDateTime.parse(str2, dtf);
    LocalDateTime lds3 = LocalDateTime.parse(str3, dtf);
    System.out.println(lds2.compareTo(lds3));
    System.out.println(lds3.compareTo(lds2));
}
```

**Update 2:**

If you want to print out a date in this format you have to use `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
}
```

This prints out:

```
2018-03-18T16:46:46.715Z
```

Comment: only one question?  if you can put in your code part about how to compare between two timestamps for example this "2012-02-22T16:46:28.9970430+00:00" and this "2012-02-22T16:46:29.0270266+00:00"

Comment: @SarruUken You can create a LocalDateTime object which you then compare. See updated response.

Comment: Mr. @gil.fernandes please, everything is ok now, but I can not figure out how to get the (current timestamp) using exactly the same timestamp format ? can you please help me in this matter?

Comment: @SarruUken Please check the second update of my answer.

Comment: you are great Mr. @gil.fernandes thank you very much from my heart